# what is the difference between piping and running commands sequentially?

Tags: unix

run is a file that processing an input from stdin and outputs a result on stdout

when I write:

```
$ ./run < in.json > actual.json 
$ diff out.json actual.json
```

I get that there is no difference

so when I write:

```
$ ./run < in.json > actual.json | diff out.json actual.json
```

I expect that it returns that there is no difference 
but instead I get that there is a difference which is everything in out.json

What is the difference between those two commands? From my understanding piping (|) executes the command on the left then the command on the right so they should be the same commands

Comment: Shouldn't this question belong to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: The advantage of piping is you can avoid storing a temporary result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding piping (|) executes the command on the left then the command on the right so they should be the same commands

That's plain wrong.

Both programs are executed at the same time; the output of the first gets redirected to the input of the second.

This means that in your

```
$ ./run < in.json > actual.json | diff out.json actual.json
```

`diff` gets started when `actual.json` isn't written, so it's empty, so all of `out.json` is new.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the diff start when ./run is finished.

./run < in.json > actual.json ; diff out.json actual.json

When you only use `actual.json` for your diff, you can do

```
diff out.json <(./run < in.json)
```

EDIT: As suggested by @Glenn I removed irrelevant examples.

Comment: There's some good stuff in here but also a lot of noise. You should stop before "I do not have ..."